# How to prevent flickering caused by toggling the visibility of the parent header on tab change using useFocusEffect in React Navigation for R Native?

Tags: react-native, animation, react-navigation, hook

I'm using React Navigation in my React Native app, and I have a **grandparent** stack navigator with a **parent** bottom tab navigator that has a **child** tab screen (KidScreen) that I want to hide the header of the grand parent stack navigator when the child screen is focused. I tried using the headerShown option with setOptions in the useFocusEffect hook, but it causes flickering and doesn't give me the desired result.

Here's my current code:

```
function KidScreen({ navigation }) {
useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      // Render a custom header for this particular screen
      navigation.setOptions({
        header: (route) => (
          <CustomKidProfileHeader
            bgColor={ColorStyles.activeColor}
            imageSrc={require("../../assets/images/Clouds.png")}
            {...route}
          />
        ),
      });

      // Reset the header options of grandparent and status bar color
      navigation.getParent().getParent().setOptions({
        headerShown: false,
      });
  
      StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(ColorStyles.activeColor);
  
      return () => {
        // Reset the header options and status bar color
      navigation.getParent().getParent().setOptions({
        headerShown: true,
      });
        StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(ColorStyles.white);
      };
    }, [])
  );
  ...
```

here is the current UI:

[image: The black rectangle is the problem I guess]

The black rectangle visible in the bottom navigation bar is the problem.

I expect the header of the parent stack navigator to be hidden when the child screen (KidScreen) is focused, and shown again when the child screen is unfocused, without any flickering. However, the current implementation causes flickering of the header when the child screen is focused and unfocused.

Any suggestions on how to achieve the desired behavior without flickering? Thank you in advance!